# Dependency not injecting While using AddRepositories - ABP Framework(6.0) c#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, abp

I am trying to register repositories in a separate module called freeswitch via ABP Framework.

Interface is IFSExtensionRepository

```
context.Services.AddAbpDbContext<FreeswitchDBContext>(options =>
        {
            options.AddRepository<FSExtension, EfCoreExtensionRepository>();
           
        });
```

Freeswitch DB Context

```
[ConnectionStringName(FreeswitchDbProperties.ConnectionStringName)]
public class FreeswitchDbContext : AbpDbContext<FreeswitchDbContext>, IFreeswitchDbContext
{
    /* Add DbSet for each Aggregate Root here. Example:
     * public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
     */
    public DbSet<FSExtension> Extension { get; set; }

    public FreeswitchDbContext(DbContextOptions<FreeswitchDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ConfigureFreeswitch();
    }
}
```

Repository

```
 public class ExtensionRepositoryEf : EfCoreRepository<IFreeswitchDbContext, FSExtension, Guid>, IFSExtensionRepository
    {
        private readonly ICurrentTenant CurrentTenant;
        public ExtensionRepositoryEf(IDbContextProvider<IFreeswitchDbContext> dbContextProvider, ICurrentTenant currentTenant) : base(dbContextProvider)
        {
            CurrentTenant = currentTenant;
        }

        public virtual async Task<FSExtension> FindByNameAsync(string extensionName, CancellationToken canceltoken = default)
        {
            return await (await GetDbSetAsync())
            .OrderBy(t => t.Id)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.ExtensionNumber.ToLower() == extensionName.ToLower() && t.TenantId == CurrentTenant.Id, GetCancellationToken(canceltoken));
        }

    }
```

The error I get while calling the class which is injecting IFSExtensionRepository is below

---------- Exception Data ----------
ActivatorChain = Castle.Proxies.RinglurUserServiceProxy -> RinglurNet.Ringlur.RinglurUserManager -> Freeswitch.Service.ExtensionManager

The issue is resolved when I use the following code

```
context.Services.AddTransient<IFSExtensionRepository, ExtensionRepositoryEf>();
```

Comment: Hi,
You also can use this configuration. FYI
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Entity-Framework-Core#abpdbcontextoptions

Comment: I got the solution , I followed this pattern for the repository naming convension

By following this article
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Dependency-Injection#exposed-services-by-convention